# Share gallery photo to ionic android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to send  an image from the image gallery to my ionic application, using the 'share' feature.

I have also added the following in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

i am using below code to get shared image

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(webintent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    function (url)
    {  console.log(url);

    }, function()
    {
        console.log('failed');
    });
  });
```

I was getting url value null.

What i went wrong?

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

FYI i am using this plugin:
https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent